# Cocoon doenst work in Productionmode, but all the javascript seems to be loaded correctly

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, production-environment, cocoon-gem

I programmed a small tool and deployed it on heroku, i added the cocoon gem afterwards for nested attributes and in my development environment locally everything works fine, but it seems like the clickhandler doesnt react on clicking the .add_fields button.

I've tried to update everything, but honestly i have no idea how to debug that problem, i dont get any error messages.

```
application.js

//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require gritter
//= require cocoon
//= require_tree .


_form.html.erb:

<div id='visitors'>
  <h3>Visitor</h3>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :visitors do |visitor_form| %>
     <%= render 'visitor_fields', f: visitor_form %>  
  <% end %>
</div>
  <div class="links">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Visitor', f, :visitors, class:    "btn btn-primary add" %>
  </div>
```

_nested_form.html.erb:

```
<div class='nested-fields form_group'>
        <%= f.input :first_name, id: 'visfirst', label: 'Firstname' %>
        <%= f.input :last_name, id: 'vislast', label: 'Lastname' %>
        <%= link_to_remove_association 'Remove Visitor', f, class:  'btn btn-warning remov' %>
</div>

part of the Gemfile

gem 'country_select', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.1'
gem 'gritter', '~> 1.2'
gem 'axlsx', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.1'
gem 'axlsx_rails', '~> 0.5.1'
gem 'cocoon', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.10'
gem 'countries'
```

Unfortunately i doesnt get any error messages. When i click the Add Fields link, it just sends me to the top of the page.

Comment: sounds like you have a conflict with turbolinks

Comment: Did you compile the assets? Executed `rake assets:precompile` ? Probably a long shot, default deployment with mina/capistrano automatically takes care of this, but this might explain. Check the javascript console (in your browser) for any errors?

Comment: Yes i precompiled the assets, unfortunately no errors  in the console. I still have'nt found a reason for the problem.

Comment: Things: how did you include the application.js? How did you deploy/configure your server: does rails process serve the assets or the nginx/apache? Ow I see the heroku tag? (not very familiar with heroku) Are all the assets correctly loaded? Can you see any js code in the browser? Is application.js loaded at all? Did you try running in production locally?

Comment: Did you solve it?